# Microsoft Excel formula doesn´t work

Tags: excel

my formula doesn´t work for various cells, like the one below...

```
IF(AND(MONTH($C$2:$C$237)=1; $B$2:$B$237="Music");SUM($D2:$D237);0)
```

It works if I run it just for one cell on each column, just like this:

```
IF(AND(MONTH($C$2)=1; $B$2="Music");SUM($D$2);0)
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you hit `F2` while in the cell and then `CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER`?

Comment: @MattCremeens, this will not work as the AND function surrounding the array'd terms will collapse the array into a single FALSE value, and will error when provided with a single test value against multiple return values.

Comment: [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5). January of this year or January of any year?

Comment: @Jeeped Any year... What am looking for in this function is: sum if month = X and category = Y (music in function I posted), but bear in my mind, there might be a couple items for the same month and category and I want the sum of those.

Comment: Would the person who downvoted this question kindly explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first listed formula there is an Array Formula. It does the same task over an entire range instead of just over a single cell. It provides an 'array' of results (basically a list of each response when the formula was tested against each cell.

In some cases a formula similar to yours could be simply fixed by entering CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER (instead of just ENTER) when confirming the formula. However, array formulas do not work well with the AND function. This is because AND takes an array of results (TRUE; FALSE; FALSE; FALSE...), and tells you if that entire array = TRUE.

To fix, convert it into 2 if statements, like so:

```
=SUM(IF(MONTH($C$2:$C$237)=1; if($B$2:$B$237="Music"; $D2:$D237;0); 0))
```

And make sure you confirm with  CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER (instead of just ENTER).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like array formulas then:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B237="Music")*(MONTH(C2:C237)=1)*(D2:D237))
```

[image]